# ¿Cómo sacar visualmente una línea de una tabla HTML?

Tags: html, css, tablas

Tengo la siguiente tabla HTML, quisiera que entre la celda que contiene el `1` y el `2` no exista una línea de separación, pero si que exista una línea entre el `1` y el `3`, ¿es posible esto?.

Debo utilizar solo https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/ porque es para poner en un mail, no una pagina HTML. Adjunto mi código:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-0lax {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es posible, fácilmente ingresas al `th` y le quitas el borde inferior, dándole `0px`, así no tendrá borde debajo:

```
.tg th {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Y luego al primer `td` (que es el número `2`), le das un color blanco al borde superior (con `nth-of-type(1)` ingreso al primer `td`):

```
.tg td:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-top-color: white;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-0lax {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg th {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.tg td:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-top-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
      <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.
Me sirvió, lo unicco que utilicé border-top: 0px para el td en vez de white y funcionó.
Saludos!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos.